# Notepad++ regex search and replace ignores my result groups

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to change several text files with questions to a format which a online learning platform uses.

I have lines with this structure: 
`\item Question in german.//Question in english.\\ %true`
`\item Second question in german.//Second question in english.\\ %false`

I need to change the line so it would look like this: 
`::Question in german.//Question in english.::[html]<p><span style\="font-size\: 14px;">Question in german.//Question in english.</span><br></p>{ %true` 
`::Second question in german.//Second question in english..::[html]<p><span style\="font-size\: 14px;">Second question in german.//Second question in english.</span><br></p>{ %false`

Only the text 'Question in german.//Question in english.' and the anser '%true' changes (the answer can either be true or false).

I was able to  find my wanted part with this regex expression:
 `(\\item )(.*)(\\\\ %.*)`

I used this 
`::\2::[html]<p><span style\="font-size\: 14px;">\2</span><br></p>{ \3` 
as replacement statement but Notepad++ result is:

```
 ::::[html]<p><span style="font-size: 14px;"></span><br></p>{
```

I also tried

```
:: $2 ::[html]<p><span style\="font-size\: 14px;"> $2 </span><br></p>{ $3
```

because I'm not sure what Syntax notepad++ v7.7 uses. The result is similar

```
 ::  ::[html]<p><span style="font-size: 14px;">  </span><br></p>{
```

I have no idea why Notepad++ ignores my groups.

***SOLUTION***

I wasn't able to solve the problem with Notepad++ . Here is the solution that worked for me:

I used this webpage https://regex101.com/ with the pattern to search: 
`^\\item\h+(\N*?)//(\N*)\\\\\h*(\S+)`

and for substitiution 
`::$1//$2::[html]<p><span style\="font-size\: 14px;">$1//$2</span><br></p>{ $3`

Comment: In my Notepad++ 7.7.1 your attempt works though a bit different outcome.

Comment: Is there a capturing issue with your np++? Try some simple replacement to narrow the problem down. Eg try to replace `(\\item)` with `**$1**` and test if the asterisks added.

Comment: @bobblebubble That shouldn't be happening on any version NPP of which I'm aware.

Comment: @bobblebubble the result is: **** - so the capturing should work.

Comment: It does not work. Where's the captured text? It should look [like this](https://regex101.com/r/dPCxkS/2) `**\item** Question`... @TimBiegeleisen In my NP++ I get exactly the same outcome [as in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dPCxkS/1) for OP's sample.

Comment: @bobblebubble you a right. I have no idea why I said that it worked. It also tried it with \1 instead of $1 and it doesn't work.

Comment: @des_viech That doesn't necessarily mean that NPP is broken.  A capture group replacement can also fail because the pattern doesn't match (much more likely here).

Comment: Does every matching line end with either `%true` or `%false` ?  Did you do the find and replace _in regex mode_ ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP's regex pattern matches, but the captured stuff is not inserted in the replacement. The rest of the replacement string is replaced. So I'd assume there is another issue.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen f.ex. npp finds 72 time the term (\\item) in one of my files. So the pattern matches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, every line ends with either %true or %false

Comment: Your current pattern _can't_ work, because the second capture group contains _both_ questions.

Comment: @des_viech What happens if you replace `(.)` with `$1_` or `\1_` ? 1.) All characters are replaced with underscores and gone - or 2.) there is an underscore after each character appended... It [should look like this](https://regex101.com/r/dPCxkS/3) if it does not, there is another issue.

Comment: @bobblebubble both variants results in 2

Comment: So this would mean capturing works. No idea anymore :)

Comment: Something [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/meAjlX/3) does work for me with either dot mode. Search for `^\\item\h+(\N*?)//(\N*)\\\\\h*(\S+)` and replace with `::\1//\2::[html]<p><span style\="font-size\: 14px;">\1//\2</span><br></p>{ \3` however I still have the feeling there is another issue related to capturing.

Comment: Your expression works with online regex but not in npp. I will use just [Online Regex](https://regex101.com/) for my workflow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve the problem with Notepad++ . Here is the solution that worked for me:

I used this webpage https://regex101.com/ with the pattern to search: 
`^\\item\h+(\N*?)//(\N*)\\\\\h*(\S+)`

and for substitiution 
`::$1//$2::[html]<p><span style\="font-size\: 14px;">$1//$2</span><br></p>{ $3`

Here is the link to the solution [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/meAjlX/4)

 Credit goes to bobblebubble and TimBiegeleisen

Comment: `\N` isn't supported in Notepad++, you must use `.` instead and uncheck `. matches newline`

Comment: Thanks @toto indeed :) Sorry I didn't know that! To be independent of the dot option you could still use [`^\\item\h+([^\r\n]*?)//([^\r\n]*)\\\\\h*(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/meAjlX/5)

Comment: @bobblebubble Weird: ^\\item\h+([^\r\n]*?)//([^\r\n]*)\\\\\h*(\S+) this results in 9 matches altough it should be 72.

Comment: @des_viech You'd need to update and share [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/meAjlX/5) with the input where it fails.